# SignalR switching from NewtonsoftJsonProtocol to JsonProtocol throws System.Text.Json.JsonException: '{' is invalid after a value

Tags: c#, json, serialization, signalr, .net-6.0

In .Net 6, when trying to use SignalR with **JsonProtocol** (System.Text.Json), my client program throws the following exception

```
System.IO.InvalidDataException: Error reading JSON.
   ---> System.Text.Json.JsonException: '{' is invalid after a value. Expected either ',', '}', or ']'. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 4090
```

Code on server side:

```
services.AddSignalR()
    .AddJsonProtocol();
```

Code on client side:

```
conn = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .WithUrl($"{_serverBaseAddress}mainHub", o =>
            {
                o.AccessTokenProvider = InitializeOrRefreshAccessTokenIfNeeded;
                o.Transports = HttpTransportType.WebSockets;
            }
        )
        .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
        {
            logging.AddConsole();
        })
        .AddJsonProtocol()
        .Build()
```

Note: everything works fine when using **NewtonsoftJsonProtocol**:

Code on server:

```
services.AddSignalR()
        .AddNewtonsoftJsonProtocol(opts =>
        {
            opts.PayloadSerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All;
        });
```

Code on client:

```
conn = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .WithUrl($"{_serverBaseAddress}mainHub", o =>
            {
                o.AccessTokenProvider = InitializeOrRefreshAccessTokenIfNeeded;
                o.Transports = HttpTransportType.WebSockets;
            }
        )
        .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
        {
            logging.AddConsole();
        })
        .AddNewtonsoftJsonProtocol(
        opts =>
            opts.PayloadSerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
        )
        .Build();
```

There is a difference, with NewtonsoftJson I specify TypeNameHandling.All but I do not know any equivalent for System.Text.Json.

Why not just keep Newtonsoft.Json? I would like to use source generators and specify a SerializerContext like below:

```
.AddJsonProtocol(options =>
{
    options.PayloadSerializerOptions.AddContext<MyJsonSerializerContext>();
});
```

which I believe I cannot do with NewtonsoftJson

Comment: Need more detail. Is this error on the client or server?

Comment: Thank you, that was on the client but after seeing your comment I checked on the server and saw a cyclic exception. I did more digging and was able to find useful information on the migration to System.Text.Json (see answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out, switching from **Newtonsoft.Json** to **System.Text.Json** is not as simple as just switching protocols in the configuration.

There is this page from Microsoft that describes the key differences between the 2 and helps with the migration:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0

As they explain, in some scenarios it will not be possible to move to **System.Text.Json**.

So in my case, I was looking at errors on the client but actually, the server was throwing a cycling error like this one:
[How to JSON serialize without cyclic error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65163728/how-to-json-serialize-without-cyclic-error)
Replacing **[IgnoreDataMember]** by **[JsonIgnore]** fixes the issue.

Also **TypeNameHandling.All** which I was using in **Newtonsoft.Json** is not supported in **System.Text.Json**. I was using this setting because of polymorphic deserialization, but in this case, they propose to write custom converters as a workaround:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0#support-polymorphic-deserialization

Comment: You never posted your DTOs, so this answer won't help others. This isn't the error thrown when there are circular references. If even the creator of SignalR can't understand what you posted ... (yes that's him)

Comment: I think the point here is that to switch from Newtonsoft.Json to System.Text.Json, its not just about changing the protocol in the configuration as I did but there is a migration process to follow (see link in the answer), that will definitely be helpful to people wanting to switch.